# Didn’t inform interviewer of layoff, what now?

Tags: layoff

I was recently laid off and it was part of a company reduction of force. I slipped into a self doubting mood after this as I’ve never been fired or laid off before.

The first week I was unemployed, a company reached out to me on LinkedIn that is in the same industry I’m in looking for someone to fill an open role I fit the description for.

When I had my first call with the recruiter I did not mention the layoff and told him I would need two weeks if offered the job…

Now that I’ve made it far into the interview process I am nervous about omitting this information.

Should I inform the recruiter before the final interview this week that I was in fact laid off since it wasn’t a performance based lay off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should I inform the recruiter before the final interview this week
> that I was in fact laid off since it wasn’t a performance based lay
> off?

Unless asked, don't offer the information.

Be prepared with an honest answer if you are asked something like "Why are you leaving your current job?" or "Are you currently working?"

Answer (score 5):

You are likely OK since it does not appear that you intentionally lie to the recruiter or interviewer from the new company.

If the interviewer or recruiter did not ask if you are currently employed, then you don't have to tell them that you currently are not employed.

However, on your resume and LinkedIn profile, you should clearly state the fact that your employment with your old company already ended at the correct month and year.

For example, if you work for the old company from Sept 2010 till Sept 2022, then you could write something like this on your resume and LinkedIn:

> Company ABC: Sept 2010 - Sept 2022

People usually include only the month and year to indicate their work history.

The fact that you ask for 2 weeks before you can start is OK regardless of whether you are currently employed or not.

Answer (score 3):

> told him I would need two weeks if offered the job

While in many places that sounds like you were stating you needed to give two weeks notice, it is also normal for some people to take a week or two for leave between jobs,

> Should I inform the recruiter before the final interview this week
> that I was in fact laid off since it wasn’t a performance based lay
> off?

maybe. If they want to talk to your current employer, or they are asking for permission to talk to your current employer, you will need to address this.

If they don't ask, I wouldn't let them know. Your current lack of income does mean that you will may not have a great negotiating position, so I wouldn't rush to tell them. But your lack of job commitment does mean that you may be able to start work a few days earlier when you do get the offer.

I am assuming that the terms of the layoff don't restrict your ability to accept this job.